# Java struts select and update lock

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, synchronization, thread-safety

We have a select query which check whether the status is edited or not if no then an update is performed on the same record with status as edited. If already present then error is displayed to user saying record cant be edited. This logic is written in dao layer which is called from a service layer which is called by a struts action.

When multiple user perform the same task at the same time we are getting two edited record. Is this because there is no synchronization??
Will Synchronizing the logic block will resolve the issue?? or we need handle using some table lock.

The application is in production. We have similar kind of logic in lots of other modules. What is the best and safest way to handle this.

We are using Struts 2 and ibatis.

Comment: How can you have two different records locked if two users are concurrently trying to lock THE SAME RECORD... ???? Assuming you are locking the record by ID and not by some other naive ways...

Comment: Seems a synchronization is already done in the persistence layer and you probably have to adjust the isolation level to suit your needs.

Comment: I suggest locking the table will do the trick. I've implemented the same in few of my projects.

Comment: @coding_Idiot Can you share some link or code block if possible

Comment: I use [hibernate locking](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hibernate+table+lock&oq=hibernate+table+lock&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j0l2.2329j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). If you use JDBC, then just [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jdbc+table+lock&oq=jdbc+table+lock&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2648j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) - there are lots of examples.